# VBA check excel worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

How can I check the name of the worksheet or workbook that the VBA macro is being run inside? To use as a conditional statement, (if workbook/worksheet name = " ", then ...).

Answer (score 1):

If the worksheet is the one displayed on the screen you could use something like this:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Name of Sheet" then
    *Code here
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get away from *not* explicitly specifying the worksheet (and workbook if more than one are open) when running macros. Specifying the worksheet is easy using a [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Every range or cell reference belonging to the worksheet simply needs a period (aka `.` or *full-stop*) as a prefix to assign the worksheet as the parent. It is only when you want to reference a different worksheet that you need to specify a different parent worksheet; e.g. copying from one worksheet to another. That is easily taken care of with a variable *Set* to the worksheet object.

Example:

```
dim ws2 as worksheet
set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
with Sheets("Sheet1")
    .range("A2:D4).copy destination:=ws2.range("A2")
    'more operations on Sheet1 here using .Range and .Cells
end with
```

With that said, if you want to determine which worksheet a cell reference like `Range("A1")` belongs to at some point in your code, get the [Range .Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) of any cell reference and you can determine the parent worksheet's [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175750(v=office.11).aspx) from that. The *External* parameter of the [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) can also be used to pull out a string cell address with the workbook and worksheet but this would require some text manipulation to determine the worksheet name.

Example:

```
debug.print Range("A1").parent.name
debug.print Cells(1, 1).parent.name
debug.print Range("A1").address(0, 0, external:=True)
debug.print Cells(1, 1).address(0, 0, external:=True)
```